# Rect in a skin with border

Tags: flex4, skinning

It is possible to draw a rect with a border, which appears left, right and top.
What I want is a tabbar with a border around everything (content and buttons), but the borderline between button and content should disappear.

I think, the easiest way would be to draw a border around a rect without the bottomline.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS "outline" command.

Something like this :

```
#tabContainer {
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    outline: black solid thick;
}
```

Comment: this is not exactly what i want. But thank you for your answer. The outline doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I see what you are asking now. Is this for a drop down menu?
If so try doing a css border-top/right/left for the button and then doing a border-right/left/bottom for the content.